# jasper report header not printed on summary page

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using Jasper reports. I have a page header, detail & summary band. The page header is repeated on all pages but sometimes when only the summary part moves into last page as the detail gets over in the page before that. The header is not printed on the last page i.e summary page.
Does somebody have any idea as to why the page header is not printed on the summary page. Is there some other way to print header on summary page.

Answer (score 21):

By default, the page header does not apply to the summary band.

Since `Jasper 3.6.1`, there is a report property that can be used to force the summary band also to have page header, called `Summary with Page header and footer`. You should check it in `iReport`, or set `isSummaryWithPageHeaderAndFooter="true"` in the `jasperReport` tag.

Comment: yshalbar, Thanks for your response. But what I need to achieve is if there is room in the previous page then the summary band should be printed there as its happening now. But if the summary band moves into the last page then the page header should appear for it. Precisely, I want page header to appear on all pages.

Comment: There is a (relatively new) report property, 'Summary with Page header and footer' that you can use. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you yshalbar, this saved my bacon! I wish rakesh had accepted your answer...

Comment: @yshalbar do you know how to accomplish this BEFORE jasper 3.6.1 (e.g. Jasper 3.5.0)

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions, before 3.7.6, you can put your content on band

> 'lastPageFooterBand',

Because the header content going to be repeated.

Other solution is:

> add a new band into your report.

In my case, I was using ireport 3.0. I tested the two situations and worked perfectly.