# Jasper reporting - Subreport with all main report details

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created a main report, I am adding a subreport now.

When I run the report, I need my main report to be followed by subreport in the next page with the main report's title and page header thing in it.

How to do this?

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of your report design? Are using iReport?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are putting your sub report into the summary section of the report.  By default the page header does not print with a summary section that goes onto a new page.  Since Jasper version 3.6.1 there is an option for having your page header print with your summary section.  See this link: [jasper report header not printed on summary page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966947/jasper-report-header-not-printed-on-summary-page)

In versions prior to this, you would need to put your sub report into a group footer.  If needed you could create a dummy group footer (you could call it "Dummy"), and have it's Group Expression = "new Integer(1)".  That should do the trick.